# Representation of semigroup of trace-class operators in terms of projectors

Tags: hilbert-spaces, compact-operators, self-adjoint-operators, schauder-basis

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. For all $t\in\left]0,\infty\right[$ the operator $A_t\in L(H,H)$ is assumed to be trace-class and symmetric. Furthermore $A$ is a semigroup, i.e.
$$A_{t+h}=A_tA_h$$
for all positive real numbers $t$ and $h$. I expect that we can prove the following theorem:

> There is a countable set $M\subset\mathbb R$ and a family of subspaces
> $(V_\lambda)_{\lambda\in M}$ such that $$\forall t:
>  A_t=\sum_{\lambda\in M}\exp(-t\lambda)P_\lambda$$
> where $P_\lambda$ is the orthogonal projector onto $V_\lambda$.

I have an incomplete and unelegant proof using a basis (see below), can someone confirm the theorem/provide a reference?

**Motivation**: I think that this formula is implicitly used in the proof of the McKean-Singer formula in [Heat Kernels and Dirac Operators](https://link.springer.com/book/9783540200628) (theorem $3.50$). For those who have the book, I think that we use $\mathrm{Str}(P_\lambda)=n^+_\lambda-n^-_\lambda$.

---

Addendum (proof based on the last paragraph of page $90$):
Firstly, according to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4686178/572841) we can simultaneously diagonalize the entire semi-group to obtain a Hilbert-basis $(v_n)$:
$$A_tv_n=\mu_{n,t}v_n$$
The semi-group property implies that $\mu_{n,t}=\exp(-t\lambda_n)$ for some $\lambda_n$ (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2177866/572841)). Hence,
$$A_t=\sum_n\exp(-t\lambda_n)|n\rangle\langle n|$$
Assuming that
$$P_\lambda=\sum_{n:\lambda_n=\lambda}|n\rangle\langle n|$$
and setting $M:=\{\lambda_n:n\in\mathbb N\}$ we should obtain the desired result, but I am not so sure about this step. (I asked a related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4686927/572841).)