# How to calculate the trace of a semigroup?

Tags: trace, semigroups, self-adjoint-operators

Let $A$ denotes a self-adjoint operator such that $Tr(A)< \infty$. Let $t\geq 0$. How to show the following
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{\infty}Tr(e^{-tA})< \infty\,.
\end{equation}
Some facts
\begin{equation}
Tr(A) =\sum_j<\phi_j|A|\phi_j>\,,
\end{equation}
where $\{ |\phi_j>\}_j$ is any orthogonal basis (it could be the set of the eigen functions of A). Moreover,
\begin{equation}
A= \sum_{\lambda\in\sigma(A)} \lambda E_{\lambda}\,,
\end{equation}
where $\sigma(A)$ is the spectrum of operator $A$ and
\begin{equation}
E_{\lambda} := \sum_{\lambda_j=\lambda}<\phi_j,\cdot> |\phi_j>
\end{equation}
is the orthogonal projection on to the eigen space of $\lambda$.

Comment: It seems I need to have $Tr(A^{-1}) < \infty$ to get the desired result, which make sense if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

My idea is to use the formula written [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4686952/representation-of-semigroup-of-trace-class-operators-in-terms-of-projectors) to express
\begin{equation}
e^{-tA} = \sum_j e^{-t\lambda_j} E_{\lambda_j}\,,
\end{equation}
which implies
\begin{equation}
Tr(e^{-tA}) = \sum_j e^{-t\lambda_j}\,.
\end{equation}
Hence,
\begin{equation}
\int_0^{\infty} e^{-tA} dt = \sum_j\int_0^{\infty} e^{-t\lambda_j} dt = \sum_j\frac{1}{\lambda_j}\,.
\end{equation}